# How to make full screen application in OSX?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, osx-mavericks, osx-yosemite

I am trying to make my OSX application full screen. Compatibility is OSX 10.9 and 10.10. I am using XIB based layout. I have searched for answers on internet, they are mostly outdated. Any suggestions?

**Edit:**

My question is different because it relates to OSX Mavericks rather than OSX Lion as mentioned in the duplicate.

Comment: have you checked out, updated March 2015: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/MOSXAppProgrammingGuide/FullScreenApp/FullScreenApp.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a Mac OSX Cocoa application fullscreen?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4921910/how-to-make-a-mac-osx-cocoa-application-fullscreen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Set Base SDK Mac OS X 10.9
2. Choose MainMenu.xib in Project navigator
3. Choose 'windowname' in Objects
4. You need to add a menu item. Choose 'Menu - View', and then drag 'Full Screen Menu Item' in Object Library into 'Menu - View'.

Did you read this: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/MOSXAppProgrammingGuide/FullScreenApp/FullScreenApp.html  ?

This might help you